# Boolean flag in nested for loops, 2D arrays check (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, for-loop, multidimensional-array, nested-loops, boolean-expression

I'm new developer and i have this question, thanks in advance.
building an tic tac toe game. i want to a horizontal check, i got it to work with counter like this:

```
var currentPlayer = 'X';

var ArrOfBoardRealTime = [['X','X','X'],
                          ['O','X','X'],
                          ['O','X','X']]; 

    function checkWinners() {
        var counter = 0;
        var winner;

        for(let i = 0; i < ArrOfBoardRealTime.length && counter < 3; i++){
            for(let j = 0; j < ArrOfBoardRealTime[i].length; j++){
                if(ArrOfBoardRealTime[i][j] == currentPlayer){
                    counter++;
                }  
            }
            if(counter == 3){
                winner = currentPlayer + ' WON ,HORI-WAY';

            }else{
                counter = 0;
                winner = 'NO WIN';
            }
        }
        return winner;
    }
```

but i want to try to make it work with boolean flag to make it a bit shorter and better. 
**NOTE""I know im working on a loooong way to solve the tic tac toe, but im learning this to learn more""**

now i've tried to solve it with boolean but it won't work, when i debugged it, it stops the check because it's false and it never enters the loop again. this is what i've tried :

```
var currentPlayer = 'X';

var ArrOfBoardRealTime = [['X','X','X'],
                          ['O','X','X'],
                          ['O','X','X']];     


function checkWinners() {
    var isWin = true; 
    for (var i = 0; i < ArrOfBoardRealTime.length; i++ ){
        for(var j = 0; j < ArrOfBoardRealTime[i].length && isWin; j++){
            if (ArrOfBoardRealTime[i][j] != currentPlayer){
                isWin = false;
            }
        }

    }
    return isWin;
}
```

Im still learning and i'd appreciate your help and tips guys. 
Thanks again.

Comment: what is the question about? please narrow to a specific problem.

Comment: Put `isWin = true` into the outer loop, before the inner one starts.

Comment: What is it that you expect your code to be doing? right now it looks like the first time you come to the other player in your check, the current player just loses.

Comment: @NinaScholz i want to use the boolean instead of the counter

Comment: @zfrisch yes the currentPlayer is "X" for now this is just for check only, i want to check if the horizontal rows are equal to current player, the function with the counter works good, but i can't get it working with boolean flag.

Comment: instead of iterating over the second array you could just use the `every` method of Arrays

Comment: @zfrisch can you write me an example please, im kinda new and im not sure how to get that done.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your outer loop doesn't stop when `isWin` is true. So you'll process the second row and set it to `false`.

You need to initialize it to `true` at the beginning of each row, then check it again at the end of the row, and stop when a win is found.

```js
var currentPlayer = 'X';

var ArrOfBoardRealTime = [
  ['X', 'X', 'X'],
  ['O', 'X', 'X'],
  ['O', 'X', 'X']
];

function checkWinners() {
  var isWin;
  for (var i = 0; i < ArrOfBoardRealTime.length; i++) {
    isWin = true;
    for (var j = 0; j < ArrOfBoardRealTime[i].length && isWin; j++) {
      if (ArrOfBoardRealTime[i][j] != currentPlayer) {
        isWin = false;
      }
    }
    if (isWin) {
      break;
    }
  }
  return isWin;
}
console.log(checkWinners());
```

Comment: Thanks, i've tried it and it works only with the first array, if i try this way:
[['X','O','O'],
 ['O','X','O'],
 ['X','X','X']];

it return false

Comment: @Barmar declare `isWin` right where it is, then define it to `true` within the first loop. You can also remove the `&& isWin` from the second loop because it will always be true.

Comment: @zfrisch Right, that fixes it. `&& isWin` will be false after it assigns `isWin = false` -- it's basically the same as putting `break` in the `if` block, which is how I would normally write it.

Comment: @alaabashiyi Try it now.

Comment: Thanks guys i tried it and now it works pretty good, and i kept the  ```&& isWin``` in the second loop so it doesn't have to check the whole array since one if them is false. thanks !! @Barmar

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.prototype.every` to check if every **cell** in a **row** is equal to `currentPlayer`.

You can use `Array.prototype.some` to check if 1 or more **rows** in a **game** pass that test.

```js
var currentPlayer = 'X';

var ArrOfBoardRealTime = [
  ['X', 'O', 'X'],
  ['O', 'X', 'O'],
  ['X', 'O', 'X']
];

function checkWinners() {
  var isWin;
  isWin = ArrOfBoardRealTime.some(row => row.every(cell => cell === currentPlayer)); 
  return isWin;
}
console.log(checkWinners());
```

Comment: this works too and it seems way better than nested loops, although i haven't learn this syntax yet, working on it. is it ES6 ?  Thanks alot though

Comment: @alaabashiyi I don't remember which version it was, but it might be ES6. Arrays are powerful data structures in Javascript. I'd suggest looking up Array.prototype on Mozilla Developer Network(MDN). It'll help you a lot! If you found the answer helpful or insightful don't forget to hit the up arrow next to the answer!

Comment: thanks again !! ill look for it, and yes the answer is very helpful. i did hit the up arrow but since im new here it tells me this: ```Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.```